# Job title acting as another higher level title

Tags: software-industry, promotion, seniority, job-satisfaction

I'm a software engineer with more than 10 years of experience working in a tech startup for 3 years now. Two weeks ago I found something very irritating for me.

Since I joined the company, I found that titles are not something very important. I thought the company sort of had a flat hierarchy until 2 years ago people started getting promotions every now and then.

Before joining my current company, I was working in a corporate. I had the title and the responsibilities of a technical lead but when I joined the current company, their offer was senior software engineer. I accepted the offer and joined after discussing the reasons with the hiring manager and I was convinced with those reasons.

After a year of joining I was moved from a team to lead another team. There was no announcement about a promotion but I was referred to as the technical lead of this new team and attending all the meetings and discussions based on this. Also, there was not any change in the title on the HR system we are using but I just thought that we don't have this bureaucracy and we don't care about what's mentioned in this HR system.

What happened 2 weeks ago is that I found that my title on the HR system is software engineer. I mentioned the matter to me direct manager during our next 1-on-1 meeting and he told me that this last change was an unintentional mistake but when I asked about the real title he said:

> "According to the system and our knowledge, you are a senior software
> engineer but you are have the responsibilities and duties of a
> technical lead. Your salary is more than any senior and in the
> starting range of a technical lead."

What should I do? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Whats the problem? You want a change in the HR system entry? Ask HR.

Comment: @Kilisi No, what my direct manager said is that the title in the HR system is correct and I was never promoted to a technical lead and I was just doing tasks and have duties and responsibilities of a technical lead without any promotion.

Comment: So in your next 1:1, ask for a promotion?

Comment: @nvoigt Most probably I will discuss any possible reason that kept they from promoting me but I'm not sure if it will be a good idea.

Comment: You don't view the pay rise as enough?

Answer (score 1):

You are making more of this than is necessary. Your boss said:

> "According to the system and our knowledge, you are a senior software engineer but you are have the responsibilities and duties of a technical lead"

That means that while the HR database says you are a software engineer, he wants you to act like a technical lead. And he expects other people to treat you like a technical lead.

He also said you are being paid the amount that a technical lead is paid.

You deal with this by:

1. Doing everything a technical lead should do, including giving instructions to other team members where appropriate
2. Introducing yourself as "Technical lead of XYZ project" whenever you meet someone who needs to know what you do.
3. Interacting with other members of your team as a technical lead should.

If anyone questions this refer them to your boss. (You might also get a short written statement from your boss if the above conversation was not written - send an email saying: "Just to confirm from our last conversation that you want me to act in every way as technical lead for XYZ project.")

Maybe ask HR nicely if they will change your formal job title, at least maybe to "Senior software engineer", or something else that indicates your seniority compared with other developers.

And finally, when you come to apply for other jobs write "technical lead" as you job title on your resume.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning someone new duties is always easier than convincing HR to agree to an official promotion. If you're dissatisfied with this arrangement, you should let your manager know in your next 1:1. Rather than phrasing it as a demand, I would start by asking what has to happen in order for the new arrangement to be made official. If you don't require an immediate salary increase, you should let him know --it should be make things move more smoothly on the HR side and your manager will probably be more inclined to help with the process. (Based on his response, it sounds like he's already under the impression that you're trying to request a pay raise).